# Saving multiple records in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have an array but when saving the records only the last record is saved

This is my code

```
        if (isset($arr["transporters"])) {

           foreach ($arr["transporters"] as $other) {
                $model->company_name = $other["transportername"];
                if($model->save()){
                $allsaved = true;
                 }

            }
            if($allsaved){
                return ['data' => "Successifully created"];
            }else{
                return ['data' => "Sorry an error occured when saving the transporters"];
            }
        }
```

By `var_dump($arr)`

It returns

```
array(1) {
 ["transporters"]=>
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
   array(1) {
    ["transportername"]=> string(2) "news"  //its not saved
  }
  [1]=>
   array(1) {
     ["transportername"]=> string(4) "event"  //only this one gets saved
   }
 }
}
```

Why cant i save multiple records

Comment: In this case you need to create new instance of `$model` in loop each time you want to save different database row.

Comment: I see it now works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a proper new model  and popuplate properly

```
  if (isset($arr["transporters"])) {

       foreach ($arr["transporters"] as $other) {
            $model = new YourModel(); // add new model 
            $model->company_name = $other["transportername"];
            ..... 
            $model->others_column  // remdeber to properly populated  with all the value you needd
            .......
            if($model->save()){
            $allsaved = true;
             }

        }
        if($allsaved){
            return ['data' => "Successifully created"];
        }else{
            return ['data' => "Sorry an error occured when saving the transporters"];
        }
    }
```